# Enum как ItemsSource для ComboBox

Tags: wpf, binding

Имеется некоторое перечисление:

```
enum DataFieldType
{
   String = 0,
   Number = 1,
   Date = 2,
   ...
}
```

Чтобы отображать пользователю человеческое написание далаю класс со статичным свойством

```
private static Dictionary<DataFieldType, string> _types;

public class DataFieldTypes
{

    public static Dictionary<DataFieldType, string> Types
        {
            get
            {
                return _types ?? (_types = new Dictionary<DataFieldType, string>
                                               {
                                                   {DataFieldType.String, "Строка"},
                                                   {DataFieldType.Number, "Число"},
                                                   {DataFieldType.Date, "Дата"},
                                                   ...
                                               });
            }
        }
}
```

Затем в ресурсах окна прописываю

```
<DataFieldsDescriptions:DataFieldTypes x:Key="FieldTypes"/>
```

И делаю привязку для ComboBox

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=FieldTypes}, Path=Types}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ConverterFieldType}"/>
```

Где **ConverterFieldType** - это поле типа **DataFieldType**, при попытке указать значение в ComboBox в окно Output вываливается сообщение:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot
> convert 'String' from type
> 'DataFieldType' to type
> 'DataFieldsDescriptions.DataFieldType'
> for 'en-US' culture with default
> conversions; consider using Converter
> property of Binding.
> NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:
> EnumConverter не может выполнить
> преобразование из
> DataFieldsDescriptions.DataFieldType. 
> в
> System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.GetConvertFromException(Object
> value)    в
> System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
> context, CultureInfo culture, Object
> value)    в
> System.ComponentModel.EnumConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
> context, CultureInfo culture, Object
> value)    в
> MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object
> o, Type destinationType,
> DependencyObject targetElement,
> CultureInfo culture, Boolean
> isForward)' System.Windows.Data Error:
> 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value
> 'String' (type 'DataFieldType').
> BindingExpression:Path=ConverterFieldType;
> DataItem='OutputField'
> (HashCode=56026160); target element is
> 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property
> is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')
> NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException:
> EnumConverter не может выполнить
> преобразование из
> DataFieldsDescriptions.DataFieldType. 
> в
> MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object
> o, Type destinationType,
> DependencyObject targetElement,
> CultureInfo culture, Boolean
> isForward)    в
> MS.Internal.Data.ObjectTargetConverter.ConvertBack(Object
> o, Type type, Object parameter,
> CultureInfo culture)    в
> System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertBackHelper(IValueConverter
> converter, Object value, Type
> sourceType, Object parameter,
> CultureInfo culture)'

Как я понимаю он не может преобразовать тип DataFieldType в него же. Это как вообще???
если сделать вот такой вот конвертер:

```
class TestConverter : IValueConverter
{
     public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
          return (DataFieldType) value;
     }

     public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
     {
            return (DataFieldType)value;
     }
}
```

Который по сути никаких преобразований не делает, то все работает.
При всем при этом это все работало на момент реализации и тестировнаия этого модуля. Есть у кого-нибудь идеи?

**UPDATE 1**

Замечено еще одно изменение в поведении: если раньше я мог использовать следующий синтаксис

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConverterFieldType}"    Value="{x:StaticMember=DataFieldsDescriptions:DataFieldType.Date}">
   ...
</DataTrigger>
```

то теперь это не срабатывает (триггер попросту не отрабатывает). Теперь надо писать так:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ConverterFieldType}" Value="Date">
    ...
</DataTrigger>
```

Ну или, если заданы числовые эквиваленты для перечисления, то в Value можно указывать соответствуещее число. Может какие-то обновки установились, раз так все поменялось?

**UPDATE 2**

Выявлено следующее: если создать окно с принципом привязки описанным в начале вопроса и приписать в App.xaml это окно как стартовое, то все работает, а вот если начать с другого окна и вызывать созданное окно в нем, то привязки не срабатывают

**UPDATE 3**

А если сделать коллекцию, используемую в качестве ItemsSource для ComboBox, свойством окна, которому принадлежит ComboBox, то привязки срабатывают на ура. В общем я в понятия не имею что случилось...:(

Answer (score 1):

Археология конечно, но...
Альтернативный способ: http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/01/08/wpf-binding-itemssource-to-enum.aspx
Способ, похожий на ваш: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18263021/how-to-set-enum-to-itemssource-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Конвертер -- это правильный путь.

Насколько я понимаю этот текст:

> ConvertBack cannot convert value 'String' (type 'DataFieldType').
> BindingExpression:Path=ConverterFieldType; DataItem='OutputField' (HashCode=56026160); target element is 'ComboBox' (Name=''); target property is 'SelectedValue' (type 'Object')

-- конвертер по умолчанию не может разобрать введённую строку.

Comment: "конвертер по умолчанию не может разобрать введённую строку" - это я понял. Проблема в том, что этот код работал раньше. Сегодня я его вовторил в новом окне и там он тоже заработал! А вот почему в данном случае он не работает мне не понятно. По сути он говорит что не может преобразовать тип А в А, что, помоему, очень странно